# 1977 better lyrics

Tags: traducción

The translations I looked up in google are incomplete or make no sense. Anyone care to provide a better translation for this awesome song?

Additional : I guess it refers to Pinochet when it says "snake". Or does this stand for something else?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28zodiac%29

Comment: Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service

Answer (score 2):

When she said "el año de la serpiente" it was meant the year of the snake, like in the chinese horoscope, following the reference to the Mercury planet (as in a zodiac chart).

Translating a song lyrics is often a hard task, and with this singer it is very hard to hear ever if spanish is my main language.
Just in case you are very interested in translating this song, and as I see most sites contains unaccurate lyrics, I will provide you the spanish lyrics as I hear it from the song; if you try it yourself (and show us), I could help you later with the tricky parts (there are a lot of tricky parts in this lyrics).

```
Mil novecientos setenta y hhh...
Mil novecientos setenta y hhh...
Mil novecientos setenta y hhh...
Mil novecientos setenta  hhh...

Nací un día de Junio del año 77
Planeta Mercurio y el año de la serpiente
Sino patente tatuado ya en mi frente
Que en el vientre de mi madre marcaba el paso siguiente
Nacer, llorar, sin anestesia en la camilla
Mi padre solo dijo es Ana María
Sí, sería el primer llanto que me probaría
Quemando las heridas y dándome la batería
Solía ser entonces como un libro abierto
Pero leí la letra pequeña del texto
Como un arquitecto construyendo cada efecto
Correcto, incorrecto, se aprende todo al respecto
Saber que algunas personas quieren el daño
Subir peldaño toma tiempo, toma año
Con mi peluche mirando lo cotidiano
Dibujos transformaban el invierno en gran verano
Papá me regaló bajo mi insistencia
Un juego que trataba de compartir la solvencia
Pero en la patio me hicieron la competencia
Fue cuando sentí mi primera impotencia

Mil novecientos setenta y shh...
Mil novecientos setenta y shh...
Mil novecientos setenta y shh...

Mil novecientos setenta y siete, 
no me diga no, que no lo presiente, 
todo lo que cambia lo hará diferente
En el año que nace la serpient(e) shh...
Mil novecientos setenta y siete, 
no me diga no, que no lo presiente, 
todo lo que cambia lo hará diferente
En el año que nace la serpient(e) shh...


Mi adolescencia fue una etapa bizarra
El cuerpo es batería y la cabeza guitarra
La orquesta narra una tonada quebrada
Para la mirada de una niña que solo talla espada
Hormona disparada, sobrepobladas
Y formación que cambian en temporadas, caminas encrucijada
Cada cual en su morada preparaba la carnada
La sagrada diablada de mirada encabronada
Mi fila la verdad nunca buscó su silla
Mi búsqueda fue mero proceso de pura pila
Pupila de poeta que marcó nuestra saliva
En la cordillera que miraba la salida
La parada militar de paso monótono,
colores polícromos, los uniformes de poco tono
De tono mi cuestionamiento, la voz hizo no, no
Mi primera rima que sonó y me enroló
Mi búsqueda no fue para mí cosa de escenario
Fue algo necesario y que marcaba ya mi fallo
Así que tú hablas más de lo necesario
Fue cuando entendí que todos quieren ser corsario

Mil novecientos setenta y shh...
Mil novecientos setenta y shh...
Mil novecientos setenta y shh...

Mil novecientos setenta y siete, 
no me diga no, que no lo presiente, 
todo lo que cambia lo hará diferente
En el año que nace la serpient(e) shh...
Mil novecientos setenta y siete, 
no me diga no, que no lo presiente, 
todo lo que cambia lo hará diferente
En el año que nace la serpient(e) shh...
```

Comment: Me encanta esa canción. Menos mal que a un nativo también le resulta difícil de entender.